# Use a user input value instead of a parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have this function which works perfectly while I enter parameters, but it's not what I need, so given the code below, how can I use a user input value instead of the parameter to search through the array and return the objects?
Please keep it as simple as possible,I'm new to javaScript.
  Please include input and button as html fields as well.

```js
carSelection = [{
    manufacturer: "Fiat Automobiles S.p.A.",
    type: "Fiat 500",
    fuel: "Eurosuper        98",
    condition: "New",
    enginePower: "101kW"
  },
  {
    manufacturer: "Kia Motors Corporation (KMC)",
    type: "Kia Sportage",
    fuel: "Euro Diesel",
    condition: "Used",
    enginePower: "185kW"
  },
  {
    manufacturer: "BMW AG",
    type: "BMW X5",
    fuel: "Euro Diesel",
    condition: "Used",
    enginePower: "195kW"
  },

  {
    manufacturer: "Toyota Motor Corporation ",
    type: "Toyota Corolla",
    fuel: "Eurosuper 95",
    condition: "Used",
    enginePower: "165kW"
  }
];


var bmw = 'BMW X5';
// var n1 = bmw.indexOf("bmw", 0);
var toyota = 'Toyota Corolla';
var fiat = 'Fiat 500';
var kia = 'Kia Sportage';



var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

function findCar(arr, searchProp) {
  var rezArr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    Object.keys(arr[i]).forEach(function(prop) {
      if (arr[i][prop] === searchProp) {
        rezArr.push(arr[i]);
      }
    })
  }

  return rezArr;
}



var item2 = findCar(carSelection, bmw);
console.log(item2);
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text"/>
```

Comment: Write an event listener that calls `findCar()` with the `document.getElementById('input').value` as the argument.

Comment: It looks like you're already trying to get the input from the user.  Is that not working in some way?  It also looks like you never use the `input` variable.  Have you tried using it?

Comment: Yes, but can't get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input html looks fine to me. You should add a button which would look something like `<button id="button">`.

Now, You'll want to add a click event listener to the button. This is basically a function that will be called whenever the button is clicked. There's a couple ways of adding the event listener but I think the best is

```
const button = document.getElementById('button'); //get a reference to the button element
button.addEventListener('click', handleClick) // specify a function that should be called whenever the button is clicked
function handleClick(){
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;//get the current value of the input
    findCar(carSelection, input) //find the car

}
```

So whenever the button is clicked, we'll go get the current value of `input` and pass that to the function you've already written.

The reason your current code won't work is that you grab the value of `input` as soon as the script loads when, more than likely, the user hasn't had time to type anything into it yet. So it will always be an empty string (`""`).